# How to convert string date (Nov 13, 2020) to datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with abbreviated month names, and I have tried to follow some other solutions posted here, such as :

```
r.Date = pd.to_datetime(r.Date, format='%MMM %d, %Y')
```

but unfortunately it is giving me a ValueError: time data 'Nov 13, 2020' does not match format '%d %B, %Y' (match). The months dates are all abbreviated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
pd.to_datetime('Nov 13, 2020',format='%b %d, %Y')
Out[23]: Timestamp('2020-11-13 00:00:00')
```